GEE - Modifying x-axis to represent time of day or day of year
I've been trying to create a graph in GEE that depicts cloud coverage % over either time of day or day of year. I've been able to make the graph, but the x-axis is labeled by "COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED/20210101T175741_20210101T175737_T13SBD", for example. I don't quite understand what it means or how to translate that to represent time of day in my x-axis.
var sentinel =  ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")


var filteredCollection = sentinel.filterBounds(UCRB)
.filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT', 'greater_than', 0)
.filterDate('2021-01-01', '2021-01-02')

var chart  = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
  features: filteredCollection,
  yProperties: ['CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT']
})
.setChartType('LineChart')
print(chart)


As explained in the docs for byFeature, you can specify an X-axis variable.

X-axis = Features labeled by xProperty (default: system:index).

you want system:time_start, or if that format doesn't work out for you, map over the features and assign a date format that you like
